# Disable submit if checkbox value has not changed from initial page-render

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that does not allow submit until the form value is changed from the initial page-render.

Everything works, except for the radio buttons. When I try to check or uncheck them, they have no effect on the button.

Anyone see what is wrong? (I want to do a check to see if one or more of the checkboxes has changed from the initial page-render)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var button = $('#submit-data');
    $('input, select, checkbox').each(function () {
        $(this).data('val', $(this).val());
    });
    $('input, select, checkbox').bind('keyup change blur', function () {
        var changed = false;
        $('input, select, checkbox').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() != $(this).data('val')) {
                changed = true;
            }
        });
        $('#submit-data').prop('disabled', !changed);
    });
});
```

## Edit:

Checkbox html:

```
<input checked="checked" id="contactemail" name="contactemail" type="checkbox" />
<input id="contactsms" name="contactsms" type="checkbox" />
<input checked="checked" id="contactphone" name="contactphone" type="checkbox" />
```

## Edit 2:

New code from answer from Marikkani Chelladurai. It is almost working, but it only works if the checkbox is not checked initially, and then checked by the user. [Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7YLGa/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var button = $('#submit-data');

    $('input, select').each(function () {
        $(this).data('val', $(this).val());
    });


    $('input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox]').each(function (e) {
        $(this).data('val', $(this).attr('checked'));
    }); //For radio buttons

    $('input, select').bind('keyup change blur', function (e) {

        var changed = false;


        if (e.target.type == "radio" || e.target.type == "checkbox" ) {
            if($(this).data('val') !=  $(this).attr('checked')){
                changed = true;
            }
        } else {
            if ($(this).val() != $(this).data('val')) {
                changed = true;
            }
        }

        $('#submit-data').prop('disabled', !changed);

    });

});
```

[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7YLGa/2/)

Comment: for radio button you need to check for the `checked` property and not the value

Comment: The value of radio buttons and checkboxes will be same before and after changed. You've to get the checked attribute... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle radio buttons and checkboxes by a different way as follows

$('input, select').not('[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        $(this).data('val', $(this).val());
    });

```
$('input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox]').each(function (e) {
    $(this).data('val', $(this).is(':checked'));
}); //For radio buttons

$('input, select').bind('keyup change', function (e) {

    var changed = false;

    if (e.target.type == "radio" || e.target.type == "checkbox" ) {
       console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
        console.log($(this).data('val'));
       if($(this).data('val') !=  $(this).is(':checked')){
            changed = true;
        }
    } else {
        if ($(this).val() != $(this).data('val')) {
            changed = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems like it is almost working, but not quite. This script only works if the checkbox was initially unchecked. I want to test/check if the checkbox has changed from the initial page render.

Comment: Post the issues or final result here so that everyone could know the solution.

Comment: @Garreth00 I'll check that.

Comment: @Garreth00 Updated the Fiddle and my answer. Please check that. Hope its working fine. And let me know if there any issues...

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, `radio` buttons use the `checked` property. Pass in `event` to your `each` and check the `target.type`:

```
$('input, select, checkbox').each(function (e) {
    if (e.target.type == "radio") {
        //check radio
    } else {
        if ($(this).val() != $(this).data('val')) {
            changed = true;
        }
    }
});
```